# XSL-FO: Use variable within for-each select / group-ending-with statement?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

Say I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<books>
  <book>
    <name>Book 1</name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Book 2</name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Book 3</name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Book 4</name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Book 5</name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Book 6</name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Book 7</name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Book 8</name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Book 9</name>
  </book>
  <book>
    <name>Book 10</name>
  </book>
</books>
```

And I have some XSL-FO that looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="books" mode="table">
        <fo:table border="1pt solid black" table-layout="fixed"
            width="100%" font-size="11pt">
            <fo:table-body border="inherit">

                <xsl:for-each-group select="book" group-ending-with="book[position() mod 5 = 0]">
                    <fo:table-row table-layout="fixed" border="inherit">
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <fo:table-cell border="inherit" padding-left="5px"
                                padding-top="1px" padding-bottom="1px">
                                <fo:block>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="0 to (5 - count(current-group())-1)">
                            <fo:table-cell border="inherit">
                                <fo:block>
                                    <xsl:text>&nbsp;</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                    </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:for-each-group>

            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
</xsl:template>
```

Right now, this code creates a table with 5 columns that displays the name of each of the books in my XML file.  First, the `for-each-group` partitions the list into 5 (or less, if there are no more left) books, then the first `for-each-select` places the book names in the table, while the second `for-each-select` figures out if there will be any empty positions in my table, and puts non-breaking spaces to fill in the last few columns.

The resulting table looks like this:

[image: picture of table]

This is all fine and dandy, but now I want to be able to specify the number of columns in my table, instead of using the current hardcoded value of 5.  So if I were instead to supply an xml file that looks like this...

```
<books>
  <cols>3</cols>
  /* list of books */
</books>
```

Is there any way that I will be able to use the `cols` node to specify the number of columns I want to see in the resulting table?  If not, is there a better way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is just necessary to use a variable like this:

```
<xsl:template match="books" mode="table">
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="xs:integer(cols)"/>
```

Then, use the variable in the select statements, like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="book" group-ending-with="book[position() mod $cols = 0]">
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="0 to ($cols - count(current-group())-1)">
```

Demo:
http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHUc/1